# Очередь запросов (nginx+php-fpm)

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm

Сайт стоит на сервере с php-fpm + nginx, после конфигураций по оптимизации скорости работы на высоких нагрузках возникла проблема которую не можем решить =)
Пропала очередь запросов, например на один url можно пачкой отправить 10 запросов и они отработают в одно время без очереди. В связи с этим возникли баги на back-end. Куда копать, уже все что мог перепробовал.

P.S Вдохновляла статься http://habrahabr.ru/post/262623/

Comment: Могу предположить, что это связано с количеством обработчиков PHP скриптов (дочерних php-fpm процессов). Для каждого запроса запускается новый PHP процесс, количество процессов ограничивается через pm.max_children. Смотрите настройки php-fpm которые начинаются на pm (process manager).

Comment: pm.max_children - Этот параметр устанавливает ограничение на число одновременных запросов, которые будут обслуживаться. Эквивалент директивы ApacheMaxClients.
т.е мне нужно только одно активное соединение на клиента, выставив pm.max_children = 1 пока у клиента А не отработает скрипт, клиенты Б и С будут его ждать.

Comment: Логично что не хотелось бы блокировать ) Может стоит пересмотреть реализацию и не зависеть от количества PHP процессов. 

Как вариант, в начале выполнения сценария можно сохранять состояние (выполнение в процессе) и при по следующем обращение проверять это состояние, по окончанию это состояние сбрасывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP-FPM держит пул процессов для обработки входящих запросов, количество параллельных запросов ограничено размерами этого пула (`pm.max_children`).

Если у вас есть возможность менять код бэк-энда, то можно использовать файловые блокировки, что бы изолировать потоконебезопасный код, например:

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { // выполняем эксклюзивную блокировку, параллельные процессы будут ждать возможности выполнить блокировку
    ... // выполняете что-там у вас не работает параллельно
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // отпираем файл
} else {
    echo "Не удалось получить блокировку !"; // такого не должно происходить.
}

fclose($fp);
```